# How can I prevent objects from blocking ButtonDownFcn callback in a figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a plot of an image, made with `imagesc`.  I'm developing a workflow where a user can click on the image and interactively overlay a curve.  My first issue was that the ButtonDownFcn for the figure is blocked by the image. I worked around this by setting the ButtonDownFcn on the image object instead (and walking back up the parents to get to the figure). Now I'm finding that the curve I'm plotting can also block callbacks intended for the image.

My searches have indicated that I should be able to disable the "hittest" property to prevent the problem, but this has been ineffective for both the image and plotted lines.  Suggestions?

Example:

*file 1*

```
function testCallback(src,data)
disp('Hello')
```

*file 2*

```
fig = imagesc(rand(100,100));
set(fig,'ButtonDownFcn',@testCallback);
hold on
plot([0 100],[0 100],'m-','linewidth',5,'hittest','off')
```

Unable to trigger callback when clicking on the line.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. [HitTest](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html#bubwptp-1_sep_shared-HitTest) should work.

Comment: See edits for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the button down function for the line that you add.  Change your plot command to this:

```
plot([0 100],[0 100],'m-','linewidth',5,'ButtonDownFcn',@testCallback)
```